# 'Device Category' in Google Analytics is always 'Desktop' when user uses Android or iOS App

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For 100% users, that use native Android or iOS application, Google Analytics detect 'Device Category' as 'desktop'. Why is that? How does it work? Is there any way to configure it? 
Also how does Google Analytics recognize device model, when users use Android app? 
Thanks.